# How to use pass the activity to an dagger module using the new `dagger-android`

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

```
Android Studio 3.4
dagger-android 2.21
```

How to use pass the `activity` to an dagger module using the new `dagger-android`

Before using the older version of dagger we could pass the Activity in the constructor and return that in the provider method. But I not sure how to do that with dagger-android

I have the following module. However, dagger doesn't now about the `ForecastActivity`.

```
@Module
class ActivityModule {
    @Reusable
    @Provides
    fun provideRetryListener(forecastActivity: ForecastActivity): RetryListener {
        return forecastActivity
    }
}
```

The `RetryListener` is a interface that the `ForecastActivity` implements. I want to be able to inject this `RetryListener` into my `RetryFragment` i.e.

```
class RetryFragment : Fragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var retryListener: RetryListener // Inject here

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

    retryListener.onRetry() // usage like this
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.failurecase_layout, container, false)
    }
}
```

In the forecastActivity

```
class ForecastActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RetryListener {

    @Inject
    lateinit var forecastPresenter: ForecastPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    }

    override fun onRetry() {
       /* do something here */
    }
}
```

My ActivityBuilder is the following:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ActivityModule::class])
    abstract fun injectIntoRetryFragment(): RetryFragment
}
```

My component is this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityBuilder::class,
    ActivityModule::class])
interface StockComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: StockApplication): Builder

        fun build(): StockComponent
    }

    fun inject(application: StockApplication)
}
```

And my Application is:

```
class StockApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidActivityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidFragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerStockComponent
            .builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> {
        return dispatchingAndroidActivityInjector
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return dispatchingAndroidFragmentInjector
    }
}
```

So the question is when using dagger-android how can I inject the `RetryListener` into the `RetryFragment` that the `RetryListener` is implemented by the `ForecastActivity`?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find the answer for your question ? If yes, please share the answer.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy I am not sure that I did find an answer. However, dagger-android is no longer supported by google and it was not popular with the community. So I switched back to using Dagger2 instead. Dagger Hilt is another way to perform injection and is like dagger-android but much improved version of it.

Comment: Ok. How to do the same using Dagger2 ?  How to pass activity instance to its dependencies using dagger2 ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy You can use this as a reference. Here I am passing a fragment. But you can do the same for activity. https://github.com/steve1rm/pokemons/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/androidbox/pokemon/di/modules/PokemonModule.kt

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a module that provides your `ForecastActivity`, i.e.:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun forecastActivity(): ForecastActivity
```

The `Activity` will need to implement `HasSupportFragmentInjector`, and supply a `DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>`